# How to check if the string contains a valid vimeo url usng javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to check if the string contains a valid vimeo url using javascript ?

Example : https://vimeo.com/23374724 is a valid url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what "a valid vimeo url" is, precisely.  If you want it to begin with `https://vimeo.com/` and be followed by an 8 digit number, this will do that:

```
var myurl = "https://vimeo.com/23374724";
if (/https:\/\/vimeo.com\/\d{8}(?=\b|\/)/.test(myurl)) { 
    alert("matches"); 
} else { 
    alert("doesn't match") 
};
```

It's kind of ugly, because of all the `\/` escaped forward slashes, but what it does is look for the string I mentioned above, followed by a sequence of 8 digits that is followed by any zero-width word boundary or another forward slash.

Comment: Doesn't work when id digits count is greater then 8. For example, it would return false it you test url https://vimeo.com/133693532

Comment: If you want "at least 8 digits" instead of "exactly 8 digits", substitute `\d{8}` with `\d{8,}`.

Answer (score 8):

**Don't** rely on **Regex** as Vimeo tends to change/update their URL pattern every now and then. As of *October 2nd, 2017*, there are in total of six URL schemes Vimeo supports.

```
https://vimeo.com/*
https://vimeo.com/*/*/video/*
https://vimeo.com/album/*/video/*
https://vimeo.com/channels/*/*
https://vimeo.com/groups/*/videos/*
https://vimeo.com/ondemand/*/*
```

Instead, use their API to validate vimeo URLs. Here is this oEmbed ([doc](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed)) API which takes an URL, checks its validity and return a object with bunch of video information(check out the dev page). Although not intended but we can easily use this to validate whether a given URL is from Vimeo or not.

So, with ajax it would look like this,

```
var VIMEO_BASE_URL = "https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=";
var yourTestUrl = "https://vimeo.com/23374724";


$.ajax({
  url: VIMEO_BASE_URL + yourTestUrl,
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(data) {
    if (data != null && data.video_id > 0)
      // Valid Vimeo url
    else
      // not a valid Vimeo url
  },
  error: function(data) {
    // not a valid Vimeo url
  }
});
```

Comment: This is the approach we took as well. The only drawback is the 404 responses that show up in devtools when an invalid URL is provided.

Answer (score 5):

Try with a regex?

```
/^(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(vimeo\.com\/)([0-9]+)$/.test("url");
```

This should, if it start with a protocol, require it be "http://" or "https://". Then optionally have "www.". Then have "vimeo.com/". Then have a series of digits.

It's up to you what you want to require and make optional. I would think that everything but the "www." should be required, but I'm not sure of the input you're receiving/testing. To make it required, remove the `?` from the specific group (the `?` comes after the group it affects).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?:https?\:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com\/)([0-9]+)
```

The id of the video will be captured in group 1, if you need to use that. You can see it in action on [debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%28?%3ahttps?%5C%3a%5C/%5C/%29?%28?%3awww%5C.%29?%28?%3avimeo%5C.com%5C/%29%28%5B0-9%5D%2b%29&flags=&str=https://vimeo.com/23374724%20and%20https://vimeo.com/23374726).